# Sitecore, Possible to use parameters to switch between CSHTML code?

Tags: html, razor, parameters, sitecore

I have made a new widget that has two different layout designs in my CSHTML depending on customers needs. All other code is the same, it is only the HTML that is really different. Instead of having two different widgets, I was wondering if I could use parameters in the CSHTML. Then call them in the Control Properties of the widget to call that design. Pseudo code below.

---

if(parameter in sitecore = null)

{This HTML code}

else if(parameter in sitecore = scrolling)

{This HTML code}

---

I havent been able to find any examples of this online as of yet so any help would be fantastic.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You could use rendering parameters for this purpose. Rendering parameters can be used to pass parameters to Sitecore presentation components. They are normally used to define the presentation of a component.

Rendering parameters can be set on a rendering on the page by the editors (so they can decide which display is used).

More info here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lkpWgv2Pt0c or [here](http://www.nttdatasitecore.com/Blog/2016/September/Create-Rendering-Parameters-in-Sitecore-MVC).

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple options to do this in Sitecore, To switch or adjust the html you can use this option in the Experience editor.

1) Rendering parameters

Rendering parameters can be used to pass parameters to Sitecore Renderings

[Create-Rendering-Parameters-in-Sitecore-MVC](http://www.nttdatasitecore.com/Blog/2016/September/Create-Rendering-Parameters-in-Sitecore-MVC)

[Youtube Sitecore Rendering Parameters](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lkpWgv2Pt0c)

[Friday Sitecore Best Practice: Using Parameter Templates](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QjN4IXXjnLQ)

2) Compatible Renderings,
A easy way for a content editor to switch between renderings and use the same datasource:

[Compatible rendering](http://sitecore.stockpick.nl/english/the-experience-editor/)

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the other answers, you could use Rendering Parameters which will allow your authors to select a value on the Rendering Properties and then to decide on the logic to run. This will require your user to make a change after adding component to the page.

An alternative option is to make use of the `Parameters` field on the View / Controller Rendering. This will allow you to define 2 separate Renderings in Sitecore, and allow your editors to select the variant they require. Coupled together with [compatible renderings](http://sitecore.stockpick.nl/english/the-experience-editor/) will allow your editors to quickly switch between the variants.

On the View Rendering/Controller Rendering, set the Parameters field as required, e.g.:

`Parameters: ShouldScroll=true&WidgetClass=alert`

Then in your code you can access these parameters:

```
@using Sitecore.Mvc.Presentation
@{
    RenderingParameters parameters = Sitecore.Mvc.Presentation.RenderingContext.CurrentOrNull.Rendering.Parameters;
    bool shouldScroll = MainUtil.GetBool(parameters["ShouldScroll"], false);
    string widgetClass = parameters["WidgetClass"];
}

@if(shouldScroll)
{
    <div>Keep Scrolling!</div>
}
else if (widgetClass == "alert")
{
    <div class="@widgetClass">OH NO!</div>
}
```

You can [read more in this similar answer](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/a/3049/135) I previously provided.